# Most efficient way to use a condition statement containing HTML

Tags: php, conditional-statements

To display a form when a user is logged in, is it best to store it in a variable and echo it out?

option 1

```
<?php $form  =    "<div><form id=\"login\"></form></div>"; ?>

<html>
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
      { 
       echo $form;
      }
 else {
       echo"<li><a href=\"logout.php\">Sign Out</a></li>";
      } ?>
</html>
```

or tap in and out of php?

option 2

```
<?php  if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) 
          {?>
            <div><form id=\"login\"></form><div>
    <?php } 
       else
          { ?>
            <li><a href="logout.php">Sign Out</a></li>
          }?>
```

Comment: Use whatever way is easiest for you to read and understand later when you go to maintain it.

Comment: option 1: your html-chunk is invalid, you should close the opened `<div>` - option 2: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: No real difference, whatever floats your boat. I normally go for option two since I find it makes more sense when reading it back and its easier to work out what is being done and where.

Comment: @pozs oh sorry, this isn't my exact code just an example.

Comment: If you want to know which performs better for your application, profile it yourself.

Comment: tracking the open and end tags in option2 might be difficult but at the same time it would be easier to add stylesheets, attributes and css

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also include in the conditional:

```
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])):
    include('login-form.php');
else: ?>
    <li><a href=\"logout.php\">Sign Out</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't know about efficiency in this case since the differences would be minuscule. But for readability it helps to use written out statements:

```
<?php if($condition): ?>
    Do not echo out html in php. Instead just break out of it like this
<?php else: ?>
    Some else condition
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: +1 for readability over efficiency.

Comment: It's valid and something of a standard. Not explicitly, but largely preferred, or at least that's been the general consensus from the collection of programmers at our firm. I would say a good habit at the very least. Supposing you chose to apply for a job where a CTO examines your code. curlies may mean someone else gets the job over you. It can be that petty... where did his comment go? Oh well, good to say anyhow.

Comment: Nothing is more expensive than development hours - so anything that makes that more productive is commercially sound.

Comment: Thank you, not sure why my comment deleted instead of edited.

For future reference, Kai Qing's reply was to my comment:

"In your second block of code, is that shorthand valid? If so I would definitely use it to get rid of curly braces."